# fetching single column from an array PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have table in mysql named carbonated.
each row has four colums - PID,itemName,detailOne,itemImage (in that order).
So far I only have two rows, row 1: itemName = Coke and row 2: itemName - Redbull.

I am trying to do the following:

```
$STH = $dbh -> prepare( "SELECT * FROM carbonated" ); 
$STH -> execute();
$redbull = $STH -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
print_r($redbull[0=>'itemName]);
```

I know my code here is wrong, but I am trying to communicate what I am trying to do with the least code possible. I want to access certain columns of $redbull array, I don't want to print out the entire array. Is there someway I can do this?

I've tried `$redbull[0['itemName']]` for example, I want to get the itemName of row 0. 
Anyone know how I can do this?

Here is what `print_r($redbull)` shows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [PID] => 1 [itemName] => Coke [detailOne] => some details [itemImage] => url to image)
```

Comment: Can you show us what `$redbull` looks like by `print_r($redbull);`?

Comment: `$redbull[0['itemName']]` --- where did you find such a syntax?

Comment: @zerkms it's not real PHP syntax. I'm just trying to communicate the idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @BryanFajardo you're doing that badly. It should be `$redbull[0]['itemName']`.

Comment: @Darren I updated what `print_r[$redbull]` dumps.

Comment: @Bryan Fajardo: so why are you guessing about syntax then? Syntax is thoroughly explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you write the syntax for getting a single key from an array of associative arrays:

```
 print_r($redbull[0]['itemName']);
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I was trying to accomplish but I couldn't find it anywhere online.

Comment: Try http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, under example #6

Comment: @Bryan Fajardo: nowhere? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-101